# Express gateway how to ignore path but use rest of the url

Tags: node.js, express, gateway, express-gateway

My configurations are as below

```
apiEndpoints:
  api:
    host: '*'
    paths: '/ip'
  approval-engine:
    host: '*'
    paths: '/app/*'
serviceEndpoints:
  httpbin:
    url: 'https://httpbin.org'
  approval-engine:
    url: 'http://localhost:8001/'
```

With proxy as

```
  - proxy:
      - action:
          serviceEndpoint: approval-engine
          ignorePath: false
          prependPath: false
          autoRewrite : true
          changeOrigin: true
```

When i make a request to http://localhost:8080/app/category the request is routed to localhost:8001/app/category

My question is can we route the request to http://localhost:8001/category. I want to ignore the paths:/app/ part in  proxy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To accomplish this, you'll need to use the [express-gateway rewrite plugin](https://github.com/ExpressGateway/express-gateway-plugin-rewrite).

You can use the `eg` CLI to install the plugin.

```
eg plugin install express-gateway-plugin-rewrite
```

Make sure `rewrite` is included in the gateway config's `policies` whitelist.

In the pipeline that's handling the request, you can use the rewrite plugin like so:

```
policies:
  - rewrite:
    - condition:
        name: regexpmatch
        match: ^/app/(.*)$
      action:
        rewrite: /$1
```

This should remove `/app` from the path before the request is routed to the Service Endpoint.